# What is the music at season 3 episode 10 at 16:40 when bakugou flies towards kirishima?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the music that started playing at 16:40 when Bakugou starts flying toward Kirishima at season 3 episode 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That song is called **Trinity** and it is from **My Hero Academia 2 Original Soundtrack Disk 2**

You can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJKGy-dEJO8&index=71&list=PLBGT0Gf50F_dzpSQpXEJVZePI6je32jZj).